# How to delete only archives with a script

Tags: bash, rm

I would like to remove all of the archives (.tar, .zip, etc) on my system.

I know how to delete files using `rm` but I'm wondering if there is a command just for deleting the archives on my system (and not regular files).

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can delete an archive like you would any regular file you have rights to:

```
rm /path/to/archive
```

To delete all the files in a certain directory or a folder with more than one file use the `-r` flag (recursive).

```
rm -r /path/to/directory
```

To delete just  .tar and .zip files in /path/to/directory/ use this line:

```
rm -r /path/to/directory/*.tar  /path/to/directory/*.zip
```

*Note*: If you get permission denied, then run the command again with `sudo` in front of it.

For more information, check out the [rm manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/rm.1.html).

Comment: But if I use ```-r``` it will delete all dir? And It is correct if i want to delete just archives? I m really new in this.

Comment: @Christina If you want to delete a single file you use `rm /path/to/file`. If you have a folder,  etc and you want to delete ALL the files within it, then you use `rm -r /path/to/file`.

Comment: Explain what you mean when you say "archive"??

Comment: An example of a archive would be a `.tar`, `.zip` or even `.deb` file. Technically, you should be able to delete a archive using just `sudo rm /path/to/archive`. If you extract the archived file, then you use `rm -r` to delete it

Comment: @ldias Hence our confusion, archive files (deb, tar, zip etc) are just files and they are removable just as any other file

Comment: I have to write a script to delete all archives from the last week. Just archives, not files.And I'm just trying to figure out what to use to tell the machine that I want just archives with extension like ```.tar``` , ```.zip```

Comment: bash supports wildcards; you can `rm *.zip` for an example.

Comment: Yes, I know it. But if I want to delete all archives no matter what extension they have?

Comment: How many different archive types do you have? you could `rm *.zip && rm *.tar`, just as a super quick dirty example.

Comment: I understood. I thought there is a specific command. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Christina Please mark this answer as correct if it answered your question.

Comment: @ldias is it sensible to run these rm commands with sudo, as a blanket solution for removing files with given extensions?

Comment: depends what is `/path/to/directory/` - `sudo` will help with files that your normal user don't have permissions... I wouldn't run that on `/` .....

Comment: Isn't that exactly why it might not be the best thing to try first with sudo and worry later :|

Comment: Use `sudo` when you need it, I cannot tell you if you need `sudo` to delete your files... if you have to ask, it's probably better not to use `sudo` ;-)

Comment: I will insert it in a script and I think that I don't need to use sudo

Comment: As a general rule of thumb best not to use sudo when it's not necessary, especially when the person asking for advice prefaces their question with "I'm really new to this"

Comment: @kurja Thanks for the advice. I edited the question to include to run sudo only if you permission denied. Is that good?

Comment: @ldias yes, the answer looks good to me now.

Comment: can't see why you should use `-r` when deleting files. if you want delete file recursive better use `find path/ -type f -name '*.zip' -delete` or globstar `rm path/**/*.zip`

Comment: @bac0n both ways to do the same thing.. Or is there an advantage with using `find path/ -type f -name '*.zip' -delete`

Comment: to use globstar you need to enable it with shopt -s globstar which isn't set as default, I think you have more control with find, for example, if you like to remove multiple .ext just add another -name '\*.tar' with rm you probably end up using extglob rm path/**/@(\*.zip|\*.tar) which may or may not be set either

Comment: @ldias `-r` is only meaningful if the argument is a directory, it deletes the directory and all its contents recursively. If the argument is a wildcard that matches the target files, there's nothing to recurse into.